# Which is the best security technique for my javascript plugin

Tags: javascript, authentication, plugins, security

My plugin is has flows depicted by the diagram below:

[image: MyPlugin.js flows]

The requirement is to make the `onclick` transaction happen after authentication. That is, **only if** the owner of the domain which contains `page.html` has registered with my site (for instance `www.MyPluginJS.com/register`) can he/she use MyPlugin.js.

My registration portal spits out a `Client ID` after successful reqistration.

My question is:

1. What is the best approach I need to use in order to make the `onclick` transaction secure?
2. What are the other parameters (eg: MD5 fingerprint) I may require to make sure that the transaction happens securely?
3. Are there any existing frameworks (for instance OAuth) that I can leverage on?

I need a way to stop people from using MyPlugin.js who haven't registered.

I am inexperienced with security techniques but I can manage to code.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: really talking about security with javascript is not realistic - I would instead find a way to allow/block access to that .js file from the server side, based on whatever auth token you got...

Comment: @Leon thanks for your time :) how do i block access to the .js file ??

Comment: You really need to wrap the business logic into the server. Anything javascript is exposed. Anyone can copy your javascript file and serve it locally, and keep in mind anyone can call any javascript function by hand using the console if they wish. Javascript makes things work nicely client side, but any important stuff has to happen server side and you must always sanitize any input from the javascript plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You could serve the JS file using some server side language and add a key/value pair to the request for the js file, pe: MyPlugin.js?key=someValue. Your script could compare the value to some DB table values where you store authorized users.

HTH,
Miguel

Answer (score 1):

By using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), you can take advantage of the function [$.getScript(url)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) to load a javascript file from server-side avoiding the use of `<script>` tag.

The idea is to point the getScript function to a server-side script that will first validate your user's session and in case the session is valid, it will return your javascript file content to be loaded or a void javascript file otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a `session` created on the server side to ensure the user is logged in. You can then check client side (for user convenience) if the session variable is set, and then validate the session server side (for security) to avoid user tampering with client side code.

You could then use AJAX to load the contents of the plugin page into an iframe. jQuery makes AJAX much easier to manage.

So the simple answer from me is to use server side scripting, and session variables to ensure security, and jQuery and AJAX on the client side for user convenience.